# Pandas column.sum() without having the index values multiply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd like this:

[image: pd]

When I take the .sum() of the columns, Pandas is multiplying each row entry by the index value.

I need just a raw count at the end of each column, not a "sum" per se. What is the best way?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you get, and the output you want instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the sum of the values, use `.sum()`. To find a count of the non-empty cells, use `.count()`. To find a count of the cells which have a value greather than 0, try `df[df>0].count()`.

```
In [29]: df=pd.read_table('data.csv', delim_whitespace=True)

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
   BPC  B-S
0    2    1
1    5    2
2    0    1
3    0    0
4    0    0
5    2    1
6    8    3
7   38   12

[8 rows x 2 columns]

In [31]: df.sum()
Out[31]: 
BPC    55
B-S    20
dtype: int64

In [32]: df[df>0].count()
Out[32]: 
BPC    5
B-S    6
dtype: int64
```